# Cannot capture local host traffic using scapy in windows

Tags: scapy

I am trying to use scapy on a windows machine to sniff the localhost traffic.
So far I have tried the following:

1. Setting filter to 127.0.0.1 (sniff(count=5, filter=="ip host 127.0.0.1")

- Nothing is returned

2. Setting the iface variable to the loopback interface, as reported in get_windows_if_list()

Nothing seems to work. Any idea what I am doing wrong or whether it is even possible to do that from scapy? Wireshark seems to have no problem capturing the local host.

```
    from scapy.all import *
    from scapy.arch.windows import get_windows_if_list
    def process_packet(packet):
        print(packet.summary())

    # interfaces = get_windows_if_list()
    # for interface in interfaces:
    #      print(interface)

    # 'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1'
    # capture = sniff(count=5, filter="port 61616", prn=process_packet)
    capture_filter = "ip host 127.0.0.1"

    capture = sniff(ifaces="Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1", count=10, 
                    filter=capture_filter, prn=process_packet)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10 or later you need to have install npcap installed. That exposes the loopback interface as "\Device\NPF_Loopback".

Also make sure the following configuration variables are set to true:

```
from scapy.all import *

conf.use_pcap = True
conf.use_npcap = True
```